# Register two custom cells with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a `ViewController` connect to a Xib file. In this Xib file I have a View, and inside this View, I have a TableView like so

[image]

I also have `LeftTableViewCell` and `RightTableViewCell` which connected to another Xib files.

[image]

[image]

Now I want to register `LeftTableViewCell` and `RightTableViewCell` in this TableView, so how to do this, my code always can not compiled.

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let items: Variable<[String]> = Variable(["Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 1", "Test 4", "Test 5"])

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//        tableView.register(LeftTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: LeftTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)

//        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeftTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: LeftTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
//        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RightTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: LeftTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)

    items.asObservable().bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: LeftTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: LeftTableViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
        cell.data = data
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    tableView.rx.modelSelected(String.self).subscribe { [unowned self] (event) in
        switch event {
        case .next(let element):
            if let selectedRowIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRowIndexPath, animated: true)
            }

            break
        default:
            break
        }
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: What error it is showing?

Comment: It says: 
`Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Register XIBs

Use the familiar register function and register each XIB to a different identifier.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeftTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LeftCell")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RightTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RightCell")
```

---

### Return the cell you want

In the cell factory:

1. Determine which cell Type you want
2. Create a cell of the desired Type
3. return the created and configured cell

.

```
items.asObservable()
    .bindTo(tableView.rx.items) { (tableView, row, element) in
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)

        if row % 2 == 0 {    // 1


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LeftCell", for: indexPath) as! LeftTableViewCell    // 2
            // Configure the cell
            return cell    // 3
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RightCell", for: indexPath) as! RightTableViewCell
            // Configure the cell
            return cell
        }

    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B4Pv.png)

Comment: how i can load in different sections ?

Answer (score -1):

you need to register new cell as a nib file

1. Create UITableViewCell class with xib
2. then register your cell in tableView

> tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

and get cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

> let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

Comment: Hi @Vadim Kozak, If I do like you, it should work, but I am looking for RxSwift way, do you know about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Khuong no, sorry